# How does this code affect the RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

What does it mean when we set a layout rule to -1?
I have seen code like:

```
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, -1);
```

Does this remove the rule?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule(int, int)

Answer (score 2):

[From the docs...](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule(int, int))

> The id of another view to use as an anchor, or a boolean value (represented as TRUE for true or 0 for false). For verbs that don't refer to another sibling (for example, ALIGN_WITH_PARENT_BOTTOM) just use -1.

so if the rule doesn't apply to a sibling (direct child of the View's parent) then you use -1.

If you want to use something like `RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TO_RIGHT_OF` then you would use the `Views` id that should be to the left of it instead of -1

Comment: I don't really understand this `so if the rule doesn't apply to a sibling (direct child of the View's parent) then you use -1.`

Comment: As in the example from the docs, there is no child to relate it to for the second param because it is relative to the parent...not another child of that parent. I can try to explain more if you need but you'll need to be more clear on *exactly which part* you don't understand

Comment: I don't understand what does `-1` signify. Is it the same as saying align to the parent?

Comment: Yes, you could look at it that way. It is aligning to the parent instead of a sibling. Though, it would have to be for params that could align to a parent. For instance, you couldn't align a child to it's parent's right or left. But you could align it with the parents top or bottom

Comment: Do you understand parent, child, sibling in this context? Because that is important

Comment: So what is the difference between `.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, -1);` and `.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,);`?

Comment: The difference is that the latter won't compile. Now, you could leave off the second param completely and then the two methods would do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the rule, you need to set the anchor to 0:

```
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, 0);
```

`-1` is used when there is no sibling to refer to when using the verb of the rule.

Examples:

- `ALIGN_WITH_PARENT_BOTTOM`  : Does not need a sibling view.
- `ALIGN_RIGHT` : Does Need a sibling; i.e. the target that this view need to be aligned to its right.